# Antd select element: how can I disable typing?

Tags: html, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to use a select element with mode="multiple". I'd like for input to be disabled, meaning that a user can only choose between existing options, not enter text. How do I do this?

My element:

```
import { Select } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
const { Option, OptGroup } = Select;

<Select
                        defaultValue={['current', 'grower', 'variety', 'varietyP90']}
                        size={'large'}
                        style={{ width: '13rem' }}
                        onChange={value => this.setState({ yield: value })}
                        mode="multiple"
                        maxTagCount={0}
                        maxTagPlaceholder="Yield metrics">
                        <Option value="current">Current Yield</Option>
                        <Option value="grower">Grower Average</Option>
                        <Option value="variety">Variety Potential</Option>
                        <Option value="varietyP90">All growers' average</Option>
                    </Select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately in v3.3 there is no way to hide the search input of Select in `multiple` mode.

We can set the input `maxlength` to zero and get the wanted result.

The offering solution is kind of a hack and I don't like it personally but I couldn't find any better solution. I tried to hide the input using css but that prevents to close the drop-list because the input is used as a trigger for closing the list on focus lost event.

```
class TagSelect extends Select {
  disableInput() {
    const selects = document.getElementsByClassName(`ant-select-search__field`)
    for (let el of selects) {
      el.setAttribute(`maxlength`, 0)
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.disableInput()
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TagSelect
    defaultValue={['current']}
    size={'large'}
    style={{width: '100%'}}
    mode="multiple"
    placeholder="Yield metrics"
  >
    <Option value="current">Current Yield</Option>
    <Option value="grower">Grower Average</Option>
    <Option value="variety">Variety Potential</Option>
    <Option value="varietyP90">All growers' average</Option>
  </TagSelect>,
  document.getElementById("container")
)
```

The working demo you can check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5kvo1m11wk).

Answer (score 2):

You can use showSearch={false}.

```
  <Select
    defaultValue={["current", "grower", "variety", "varietyP90"]}
    size={"large"}
    style={{ width: "13rem" }}
    onChange={(value) => this.setState({ yield: value })}
    mode="multiple"
    maxTagCount={0}
    maxTagPlaceholder="Yield metrics"
    showSearch={false} // <--
  >
    <Option value="current">Current Yield</Option>
    <Option value="grower">Grower Average</Option>
    <Option value="variety">Variety Potential</Option>
    <Option value="varietyP90">All growers' average</Option>
  </Select>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a kind of hack in ant selection component. (using css)

Ant Version: 3.26.6

```
<Select className="my_select_component" />

.my_select_component {
  .ant-select-search__field {
   display: none;
}
```