# Select ant design react component disable text input

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this code I want to disable text aria input for perevent user from typing .only select from menu work.

```
let sel = <Select
            showSearch
            readOnly
            style={{width: '40%', paddingRight: 40}}
            placeholder={this.props.title}
            dropdownStyle={{width: '38%', paddingRight:10}}
            onChange={this.SelectCity.bind(this)}
            {...inputProps}
            optionFilterProp="children"
        >
            {OptionSelect}
        </Select>;
```

Comment: the voted answer not works for me, I have found another way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278252/antd-select-element-how-can-i-disable-typing

Comment: the voted answer not works for me, I have found another way:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278252/antd-select-element-how-can-i-disable-typing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply disable your input field in Ant Design.

> Use **disabled**

```
<Select
            showSearch
            disabled
            style={{width: '40%', paddingRight: 40}}
            placeholder={this.props.title}
            dropdownStyle={{width: '38%', paddingRight:10}}
            onChange={this.SelectCity.bind(this)}
            {...inputProps}
            optionFilterProp="children"
        >
            {OptionSelect}
        </Select>;
```

Read the official doc for more, https://ant.design/components/input/#header

Comment: I've found that you can also use `disabled={someBooleanValue}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the official docs [antd select](https://ant.design/components/select/)

**this code is directly form docs**

```
   <Select defaultValue="lucy" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={handleChange}>
      <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
      <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
      <Option value="disabled" disabled>Disabled</Option>
      <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
    </Select>
```